# React rerendering children in functional component despite using memo and not having any prop changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have an Icon component that draw an icon and which is blinking because the parent is making it rerender for nothing. I don't understand why this is happening and how to prevent this.

[Here is a snack](https://snack.expo.io/@sharcoux/children-rerendering-despite-the-use-of-react.memo) that shows the issue.

We emulate the parent changes with a setInterval.

We emulate the icon rerendering by logging 'rerender' in the console.

Here is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
let interval = null

const Child = ({name}) => {
  //Why would this child still rerender, and how to prevent it?
  console.log('rerender')
  return <Text>{name}</Text>
}
const ChildContainer = ({name}) => {
  const Memo = React.memo(Child, () => true)
  return <Memo name={name}/>
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0)
  const name = 'constant'
  // Change the state every second
  React.useEffect(() => {
    interval = setInterval(() => setState(s => s+1), 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])
  return (
    <View>
      <ChildContainer name={name} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

If you could explain me why this is happening and what is the proper way to fix it, that would be awesome!

Comment: Are there some changes happening in your parent component continously?

Comment: We change the state onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave. This makes the icon blink

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you move `const Memo = React.memo(Child, () => true)` outside the `ChildContainer` your code will work as expected.

While `ChildContainer` is not a memoized component, it will be re-rendered and create a memoized `Child` component on every parent re-render.

By moving the memoization outside of the `ChildContainer`, you safely memoize your component `Child` once, and no matter how many times `ChildContainer` will be called, `Child` will only run one time.

Here is a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-bash-40c93?file=/src/App.js). I also added a log on the `App` to track every re-render, and one log to the `ChildComponent` so you can see that this function is called on every re-render without actually touching `Child` anymore.

You could also wrap `Child` with `React.memo` directly:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
let interval = null;

const Child = React.memo(({ name }) => {
  //Why would this child still rerender, and how to prevent it?
  console.log("memoized component rerender");
  return <Text>{name}</Text>;
}, () => true);

const ChildContainer = ({ name }) => {
  console.log("ChildContainer component rerender");
  return <Child name={name} />;
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
  const name = "constant";
  // Change the state every second
  React.useEffect(() => {
    interval = setInterval(() => setState(s => s + 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  console.log("App rerender");
  return (
    <View>
      <ChildContainer name={name} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot, this answers perfectly the original question. I have a new one because it still doesn't solve my problem in my case, because this breaks when using an HOC in the Parent. I can't explain why. I'll link the question here.

Comment: Could you take a look at this? It would be really helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645789/react-rerenders-my-memo%c3%afzed-component-when-i-use-an-hoc-in-the-parent

Comment: @Sharcoux More than happy to help! I've also answered your new question. Let me know if it's not clear enough to see if I can work on a more detailed answer.