# React rerenders my memoïzed component when I use an HOC in the parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am having an issue with an Image blinking because it is rendered for no reason, despite using React.memo, and despite non of it's props or state being changed.

I succeeded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61643658/react-rerendering-children-in-functional-component-despite-using-memo-and-not-ha/61644414#61644414) to make the correct use of React.memo to make this work, BUUUT, for a reason that I don't understand, if I use an High Order Component within the Parent component, memo doesn't work anymore and I get my blinking issue again.

[Here is a snack that illustrates the problem](https://snack.expo.io/@sharcoux/children-rerendering-despite-the-use-of-react.memo).

Here is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

let interval = null

const Icon = ({ name }) => {
  // We emulate a rerender of the Icon by logging 'rerender' in the console
  console.log('rerender')
  return <Text>{name}</Text>
}

const Memo = React.memo(Icon, () => true)

const withHOC = (Comp) => (props) => {
  return <Comp {...props}/>
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0)
  const name = 'constant'
  // Change the state every second
  React.useEffect(() => {
    interval = setInterval(() => setState(s => s+1), 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])
  // Remove this line and replace NewView by View to see the expected behaviour
  const NewView = withHOC(View)
  return (
    <NewView>
      <Memo name={name} />
    </NewView>
  );
}
```

I don't understand why my HOC breaks the memoization, and I have no idea how to prevent the blinking in my app and still be able to use HOC...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're re-creating the HOC within your render function. Because of this React can't keep any of that component's children consistent between renders.

If you move the HOC creation outside of the render, then it'll work!

```js
const Text = 'span';
const View = 'div';

let interval = null

const Icon = ({ name }) => {
  // We emulate a rerender of the Icon by logging 'rerender' in the console
  console.log('rerender')
  return <Text>{name}</Text>
}

const Memo = React.memo(Icon, () => true)

const withHOC = (Comp) => (props) => {
  return <Comp {...props}/>
}

// move it out here!
// 
const NewView = withHOC(View)
// 

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0)
  const name = 'constant'
  // Change the state every second
  React.useEffect(() => {
    interval = setInterval(() => setState(s => s+1), 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])
  // Remove this line and replace NewView by View to see the expected behaviour
  
  return (
    <NewView>
      <Memo name={name} />
    </NewView>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

Edit: I saw your comment in the other answer.

> Ok, but how can I use the HOC within my component? Because I need to provide the props and the state to the hoc...

If you do need to create the HOC within the component, you can wrap it with `useMemo` and that will also work because React will preserve your HOC reference between renders if the dependencies of the `useMemo` don't change (note: this will not work if your hook dependencies change for every render).

```js
function App() {
  // ...
  const NewView = useMemo(() => withHOC(View), []);
}
```

Although this works, it can be kind of wonky. In general, hooks and HOCs are not patterns to be used together. The React core team created hooks to replace HOCs. Before you continue down that road, I would attempt to see if you can write your HOC as a hook. I think you'll find that it's a lot more natural.

Comment: @Sharcoux I updated my answer. Wondering if it helps!

Comment: It helped. Thanks !
I created rn-css that is a replacement for styled-component and handles a much wider set of CSS for react-native. But I don't see how I can have the kind of syntax styled-components propses without using HOC... But I will think about it

Answer (score 2):

On every re-render you create a new `NewView` so the old one (along with your `Icon`) will be destroyed for the new one. So, it wasn't actually a re-render that was happening on the `Icon`, but a totally new render of a **new** `Icon`.

If you move `const NewView = withHOC(View)` outside your `App` function, your `HOC` will be called once, creating a `NewView` that will be used on every re-render and this will prevent your `Icon` from also being destroyed and as you have it memoized, you are safe from unnecessary re-renders.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

let interval = null

const Icon = ({ name }) => {
  // We emulate a rerender of the Icon by logging 'rerender' in the console
  console.log('rerender')
  return <Text>{name}</Text>
}

const Memo = React.memo(Icon, () => true)

const withHOC = (Comp) => (props) => {
  return <Comp {...props}/>
}

const NewView = withHOC(View);

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0)
  const name = 'constant'
  // Change the state every second
  React.useEffect(() => {
    interval = setInterval(() => setState(s => s+1), 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])
  // Remove this line and replace NewView by View to see the expected behaviour
  return (
    <NewView>
      <Memo name={name} />
    </NewView>
  );
}
```

To better understand what's happening, I added a log [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-frost-khq8s?file=/src/App.js) on your `Icon` component so you can see that the component unmounts on every parent re-render, while it's forced to be destroyed by the creation of a totally new `NewView` with a **new** memoized `Icon`.

Comment: Ok, but how can I use the HOC within my component? Because I need to provide the props and the state to the hoc...

Comment: You can pass your props/state like `<NewView myName={name} myStateValue={state}>...`. Take a look at [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-brattain-wq4vc?file=/src/App.js). I use a custom `View` component instead of the one from `react-native` so I can log the values I pass for the sake of the example

Comment: Oh, I think that I see! OK, I will try that then